# oracle 10g:No command 'dbca' found , even when PATH set

Tags: oracle10g, oracle-xe

I have properly set my PATH to **$ORACLE_HOME/bin** and rest of the exe are working fine but I am not seeing "dbca" anywhere in that directory, though each source says that it should be there. It also doesn't show up in my menu of Oracle 10g express edition.

Has someone faced similar problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle XE doesn't include dbca.

The licensing terms don't allow for more than once instance on a given server, see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/license.102/b25456/toc.htm under "License Rights": "1. Express Edition is limited to a single instance on any server;" and given that XE comes with a preconfigured database it makes little sense to include dbca.

Comment: i think you are right... reading on similar problems gave me somewhat same idea but wasn't sure until now.